# Set RTS on Close - option not found

Tags: device-manager

I'm trying to enable the "Set RTS On Close" option.  This is supposed to be located in:
 Device manager -> Ports -> USB to Serial Comm Port -> Properties -> Port Settings -> Advanced

The "advanced" screen on mine however gives no such option.  I have tried this on 3 PCs; two running Windows 7 and one on Windows 8. But they all display the same thing. See screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2uzt09f/8

[image]

There are also several other "Miscellaneous Options" that don't appear (but appear for other people).  I suspect these options are controlled by the driver.  The driver is "Prolific" and used for an Arduino chip.  It installs automatically when the USB is plugged in.  Perhaps if I could force it to use a different driver that might fix it but I don't know which one.

**EDIT: Does no one else have this problem? The only other person I could find with this problem was in a forum posted here but he didn't really get any answers http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/stopped-on-unknown-problem**

Answer (score 1):

This option is available when you install the FTDI driver instead of the Prolific one. use this page http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm to find the suitable driver (not executable but rather the inf file)